# Displaying attributes before type casting upon model validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, casting

I have a form where the user can enter a number. The user should only enter whole numbers into the form and there is a model-level validation to check that. The data, of course, come in as a string in the params and are cast to the correct data type (int) by Rails.

If the user enters incorrect data into the particular form field, like a letter or decimal, the validations do not pass and the form is re-rendered. When the user is taken back to the form, however, the inputted data are not shown -- the cast data appear in the field. Is there any way to display the attributes before type casting back in the form upon validation failure?

Comment: What do you mean by typecasting?

Comment: @Ruslan I mean how Active Record automatically type casts all input so that it matches the database schema.

Comment: So i dont get your question. ActiveRecord will automatically try to cast the data to the types of the database. It does what it's supposed to do

Comment: @Ruslan, I understand that. I think the concrete details of what I'm running into will probably help clarify my question. I'm going to edit my original post.

Answer (score 6):

There is a `_before_type_cast` helper in rails

You can use it like this:

```
u = User.first
u.phone
u.phone_before_type_cast
```

Alternatively in your form, you can populate the field with the value in `params` if its there.

Will help you more if you post the form code snippet

Comment: This was very useful for validating some Boolean fields in rails